# Caption of figure not centering in report class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I am using a `report` class and trying to make any caption of the images to the center (the image comes in the center not the caption). These are the packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{isotope}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{dcolumn,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{asudis}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{microtype}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

If I include an image the image is centered not the caption:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics [width=0.65\columnwidth]{./Figures/petsc_images/drawing-3.jpg}
  \caption{\label{dev_hemt}2D GaN HEMT used for the validation.} 
\end{figure}
```

[image]

It looks like the figure attached. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please from your code fragments compose complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem.  Help us to help you!

Comment: Where we can find package `asudis` ? If I remove it from preamble, and compose MWE from your code fragments , I get expected result: caption is centered.

Comment: Thanks Zarko for pointing it out, the asudis package is here in github : https://github.com/shumway/asudis

Comment: please make the code you post an example of the problem you are asking about, a single small document with a misplaced caption, remove any packages not needed for the problem.

Comment: do you need that package to see the issue? If not do not make everyone install non standard code, delete it from the example, if you do need it then the problem is in that package so make an example just using that package and remove all the others.

Comment: that package does `\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{% #1 is e.g. Figure 1, #2 is captiontext
  \singlespace
  {\textbf{#1:} #2\par}
}
`  so redefining captions.....

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for the help! That worked!

Answer (score 1):

You should post a more reasonable test document but the non standard `asudis` package does

```
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{% #1 is e.g. Figure 1, #2 is captiontext
  \singlespace
  {\textbf{#1:} #2\par}
}
```

so redefining captions over-riding your setting from the caption package.